# What is the right algorithm to detect segmentations of a line chart?

Tags: time-series, machine-learning

To be concrete, given 2D numerical data as is shown as line plots below. There are peaks on a background average movement (with small vibrations). We want to find the values of pairs (x1, x2) if those peaks drops down to normal; or (x1) only if the line doesn't back to the normal.
[image: how to find x1 and x2 from data without plotting?]
[image: how to find x1 from data without plotting?]

There are thousands of such 2D data.

What is the right statistic or machine learning algorithm to find x1 and x2 above without plotting?

Comment: what is the data generating process ? is it time series ?

Comment: Yes, it is time series. x is time

Comment: If you post a sample of your data , I will illustrate ARIMA modelling with Intervention Detection which I believe will help solve your problem. Detecting change points in time series is a common problem across all disciples and can be the result of either the impact of an unspecified exogenous variable or changes in either model parameters or error variance..

Comment: disciplines not disciples BUT perhaps more statisticians should be disciples of good practice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you have in hand is called outlier detection in time series in analysis. There are three three major forms of outliers:

1. Level Shifts (permanent shift in the level of series)
2. Additive Outliers (temporary outlier pulse)
3. Temporary Changes.

There are several methods and tools that will be able to do this. Two classic approaches within ARIMA framework are:

- [Tsay's Approach](http://www.unc.edu/~jbhill/tsay.pdf)
- [Chen and Liu's Approach](http://amstat.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/01621459.1993.10594321#.VYnHtPlVhBd)

Chen and Liu's approach is implemented in tsoutliers package in R. Other software packages such as SPSS/SAS/Autobox have automatic outlier detection algorithms.

Below is an example in `R` and `tsoutliers` package using a dummy data similar to your example and the sample data plot is from expsmooth package:

[image]

```
library(expsmooth)
library(tsoutliers)

data <- hospital[,20]
plot(data)

identify.outliers <- tso(data,  types = c("AO", "LS", "TC"))
identify.outliers
plot(identify.outliers)
```

Running the above code, the tsoutlier package was able to identify inflection point at 13 and 37. See below for the results and plots.

[image]

```
Series: data 
ARIMA(1,0,0) with non-zero mean 

Coefficients:
          ar1  intercept     LS13      LS37
      -0.2834   266.9890  52.0028  -75.9691
s.e.   0.1044     4.5006   5.5221    3.8625

sigma^2 estimated as 386.3:  log likelihood=-369.41
AIC=748.83   AICc=749.6   BIC=760.98

Outliers:
  type ind    time coefhat   tstat
1   LS  13 2001:01   52.00   9.417
2   LS  37 2003:01  -75.97 -19.668
```

You could also try structural time series analysis such as Unobserved Components Model, which can detect outliers and level shifts in data.

Comment: Without actually having your "representative data", it is actually impossible to definitively say BUT upon inspection your model incorporates a differencing factor which is identified assuming no interventions i.e. an analysis of the (interrupted) original series. The flaw in your approach/software is that it doesn't identify the ARIMA component AFTER the level shifts have been identified. Good software performs a much more rigorous approach. Please post your representative data and I will use AUTOBOX to automatically identify the joint structure.

Comment: Sorry .... your model does not have a differencing factor but and an AR(1) factor . I would have thought the original series would have had an acf suggesting non-stationarity .The point I was trying to make is that it is not always correct to do ARIMA first.

Comment: @IrishStat, I agree with you completely. That is the flaw in some major software that I have used in the past.

Comment: The puzzle is even more complex when you have user specified predictor series to consider. This is why AUTOBOX executes a tournament approach to determine (in each case) the optimal sequencing of memory,dummies and causal structure identification procedures.,